# What type of API or Algorithm is used to generate session ids?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, api

What kind of API or algorithm is normally used to generate session ids? For something like an online game?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [UUID-v4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29). Implementations are available in pretty much any language. Here is one for C++:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/ooid/

Answer (score 0):

i++?

And you can make it a string and hash (MD5) the result.

Comment: No. MD5ing a monotonically incrementing integer does not provide any benefit for "hiding" the fact that you are using a poor system. If I get session IDs `b026324c6904b2a9cb4b88d6d61c81d1`, `26ab0db90d72e28ad0ba1e22ee510510` and `6d7fce9fee471194aa8b5b6e47267f03` from your web service / app, something like this [reverse md5 hash](http://md5.rednoize.com/) will quickly tell me that you are using a poor system for generating your IDs. Your system will become very vulnerable because I can then substitute my session ID for others very easily.